# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setRaw

Tags: hbase

I am trying to use the "KEEP_DELETED_CELLS" feature available in HBase to identify the records which are deleted from a table. Basically my use case is - I would like to identify the records which are deleted from HBase during a particular time period (let's say last 1h for example)

To identify the records which are deleted, I am using the RAW feature avaialble in HBase. The RAW feature is working fine while I run the program from my local machine, but when I trigger it from our cluster (Cloudera setup), it is throwing a NoSuchMethod Error.

I am sure this is because of some jar mismatch in my cluster, but I could not figure out what is causing the issue.

```
val hbaseTable = con.getTable(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf("line_items"))
val scan = new Scan()
scan.setTimeRange(startTime,endTime)
scan.setRaw(true)
```

The version of jar available in my cluster classpath is below.

```
hbase-client-1.2.0-cdh5.11.0.jar
hbase-client.jar
```

Note:- I've decompiled both of these jars and can see setRaw method inside both of these jars.

Answer (score 0):

This is very typical Hadoop issue.

1. Is your executable jar a fat jar ? Please check the dependency tree of the dependencies of your executable jar.
2. Please check you hbase-site.xml / other hbase config files.
3. Are you running your job through any orchestrator like oozie, check the jars hosted on these configs/HDFS.
4. Please validate the hbase version against which you have build the jar and the version in your cluster.

Comment: Neha, I tried with both fat jar and normal jars, both doesn't makes any difference. And I am running the job through spark, so I checked the spark classpath and can see the hbase jars available in the classpath. Please note I am able to connect to the same hbase instance while I ran from local machine, and the issues occurs only while I build a jar and execute the job in my cluster. The only difference is in the versions of jar which are available in local and in cluster. In local I build the jar using the 1.4.2 version of hbase while in cluster the corresponding version is 1.2.0

Comment: Exactly -  "In local I build the jar using the 1.4.2 version of hbase while in cluster the corresponding version is 1.2.0" , Check the diff for both the versions. I had the same issue with hbase 0.98 to 1.0

Comment: I decompiled both versions and both have setRaw method available.